# SQL - How to add count in where clause condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count, where-clause

My current query has information as below :

```
| employee_no | employee_name | employee_dept | company_id |
------------------------------------------------------------
|    P101     |     John      |      C1       |    comp1   |
|    P101     |     John      |      C1       |    comp2   |
|    P102     |     Mary      |      C2       |    comp1   |
```

This is a simplified version of the query result. Currently, the result I want is as below :

```
| employee_no | employee_name | employee_dept | company_id |
------------------------------------------------------------
|    P101     |     John      |      C1       |    comp2   |
|    P102     |     Mary      |      C2       |    comp1   |
```

I want the query to check if there are two records of the same employee, the query should take the comp2 record.

Comment: Is there a proper sequence ( or date) to determine the last row/observation ?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Then the answer provided will satisfy your desired results based on the provided sample.  You should really consider at least an identity to maintain the proper sequence and a true uniqueness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will select the last row ordered by `company_id desc`  **However,** this would be alpha sort and NOT necessarily proper sequence.  So, if there is an identity or an effective date, use that instead of `Order By company_id`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By employee_no Order By company_id desc)
```

Comment: @TheLegend28 Happy to help